# How would i do this in jsdoc

Tags: jsdoc

This is the code im trying to change from typescript into jsdoc comment.

```js
export interface ButtonProps
  extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
    VariantProps<typeof buttonVariants> {
  asChild?: boolean
}
 
const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
```

Comment: I would put the definition for `ButtonProps` into a `.d.ts` file and reference it from your jsdoc comment. Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: buttonVariant is a variable which is defined above the export

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to import buttonVariant into the .d.ts from the js file